# Xamarin Forms - How To Use A ListVIew

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to populate a listview with a customcell I made. I know how to do it with a tableview, but i have no idea how to do it with a listview. Can someone explain to me please, thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms - Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344887/xamarin-forms-listview)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse the very rough snippet of code but it is merely to explain the concept behind listviews and databinding.

In my example below I create a listview, assign a custom viewCell and bind the view cell to a model. The model data is populated by XML data retrieved from the server(Code emitted for simplicity). Simpler implementations can be done should you require a listview with hardcoded data.

I suggest reading through the http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/ and researching the MVVM principle

Additionally the best example code I have found to go through is an enlightening application written by James Montemagno https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms

```
public TestPage()
  {

     private ListView listView; // Create a private property with the Type of Listview named listview
     listView = new ListView(); //Instantiate the listview 
     var viewTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell)); //Create a variable for the custom data template
     listView.ItemTemplate = viewTemplate; // set the data template to the variable created above 

 this.Content = new StackLayout()
  {
    Children = {
    listView
  }
};

}
```

### Custom View Cell:

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomViewCell()
    {

        Label Test = new Label()
        {
            Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(17),
            TextColor = Helpers.Color.AppGreen.ToFormsColor(),
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        var image = new Image();
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("testing.png");

        Label Test2 = new Label();

        tour_Desc.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Test");
        round_Desc.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Test2");

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

            RowDefinitions = 
            {
                new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto },
                new RowDefinition {Height = 1}
            },
            ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Auto},
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = 80 }
            }
            ,BackgroundColor = Color.White,
        };

        grid.Children.Add(image, 0, 0);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(image, 2);

        grid.Children.Add(tour_Desc, 1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(tour_Desc, 2);

        grid.Children.Add(Test, 1, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(Test2, 1, 2);

        this.View = grid;
    }

}
```

### View Model:

```
public partial class GamesResult
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public string Test1 { get; set; }
}
```