# How to get data from JSON sub array using Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I have a updated JSON table like the following

{ "Students" : [ {"name": "Alex", "lastname": "Dean", "Properties" : [{"iq":120, "hair": "black", "glasses": "yes", "Grades" : [{"Math": 44, "Lit": "88"}]}, {"iq":120, "hair": "blond", "glasses": "yes", "Grades" : [{"Math": 22, "Lit": "81"}]}, {"iq":144, "hair": "brown", "glasses": "yes", "Grades" : [{"Math": 44, "Lit": "88"}]}, {"iq":120, "hair": "red", "glasses": "yes", "Grades" : [{"Math": 44, "Lit": "88"}]}]}]}

I managed to get the name and last name that are not inside sub arrays but couldn't figure out how to get the other data that are inside the sub arrays. Inside the array "Students" there is a subarray called "Properties" and another sub array inside "Properties" called "Grades".

How do I get "hair" and "math" properties?

Here is what Im doing to get name and last name.

Here is my WebService class

```
public class WebService
    {
        public WebService ()
        {

        }

        public async Task<Rootobject> GetStudentInfoAsync (string apiurl) {

            var client = new HttpClient (); 

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(apiurl));

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Here is the view model I came up with. Why doesn't it work. I am not getting the values.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Grade
    {
        public string Math { get; set; }
        public string Lit { get; set; }

    }

    public class Property
    {

        public int iq { get; set; }
        public string hair { get; set; }
        public string glasses { get; set; }

        public Grade[] Grades { get; set; }

    }
    public class StudentInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }

        public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

        public string StudentName {
            get{ return String.Format ("{0}", name); }
        }
//Why isn't the following code work? I am not getting the values and I get errors.

        public string HairColor {
            get{ return String.Format ("{0}",Property.hair); }
        }
        public string MathGrade {
            get{ return String.Format ("{0}", Property.Grade.Math); }
        }

    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public StudentInfo[] students { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And here is how I populate my list view with student names

```
var sv = new WebService();
            var es = await sv.GetStudentInfoAsync(apiurl);
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {

                listView.ItemsSource = es.students;
            });
var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(TextCell));

            listView.ItemTemplate = cell;
            listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "StudentName");
```

Comment: Are you getting anything for the `Properties` array?

Comment: No. Not getting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a property called `Property` which does not exist in your class.  Instead, your class has an array of `Property` objects:

```
    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }
```

Similarly your `Property` class has an array of `Grade` objects not a single `Grade`:

```
    public Grade[] Grades { get; set; }
```

Thus you must index into the array to find a specific `Property` or `Grade`.  If you *always* want to use the *first* entry in each array, this can be easily done with [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public string StudentName {
        get{ return String.Format ("{0}", name); }
    }
    public string HairColor {
        get{ return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).Select(p => p.hair).FirstOrDefault(); }
    }

    public string MathGrade {
        get { return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).SelectMany(p => p.Grades ?? Enumerable.Empty<Grade>()).Select(g => g.Math).FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
}
```

And then, to test:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);
        Debug.Assert(root.students.Length == 1 && root.students[0].HairColor == "black" && root.students[0].MathGrade == "44"); // No assert.
```

**Update**

You cannot get "'hair' of all 4 students" as a property of `StudentInfo` since, in your JSON, each student has one and only one entry in its `"Properties"` array.  You can see this more clearly if you post your JSON to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  To get the hair colors or names of all students you need the root object:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);

        var hairColors = root.students.Select(s => s.HairColor).ToArray();
        var studentNames = root.students.Select(s => s.StudentName).ToArray();
```

**Update 2**

In your updated question it does indeed appear that a single "student" object has multiple hair color properties, multiple math grades, and so on.  In that case, if you wish to display them as a single string, you will need to combine them somehow, for instance as comma separated values:

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public string StudentName
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public string[] HairColors
    {
        get
        {
            return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).Select(p => p.hair).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public string HairColorCSV
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", HairColors); }
    }

    public string[] MathGrades
    {
        get
        {
            return (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).SelectMany(p => p.Grades ?? Enumerable.Empty<Grade>()).Select(g => g.Math).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public string MathGradeCSV
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", MathGrades); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error The name `Enumerable' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Carell - I thought Linq was available in xamarin forms.  Try adding `using System.Linq;` and a reference to `System.Core.dll`.  See [System.Linq namespace doesn't resolve?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4655/system-linq-namespace-doesnt-resolve)

Comment: Thanks. But this is only getting the first student. How do I get all of the values? Above I have shown only one student but there is much more.

Comment: @Carell - You asked, "How do I get "hair" and "math" properties?".  Is that your problem, or do you have a different problem?  Because that's the question I tried to answer.

Comment: Yes you did answer my question and I will accept your answer. But what would I do to get "hair" of every student if there are multiple students?

Comment: @Carell - You mean, how to show both `HairColor` and `StudentName` for each student in a listview?  I'm not an expert on xamarin forms, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345576/xamarin-forms-how-to-use-a-listview

Comment: No, what Im saying is your code only returns the values for the first student. Is there a way to get the values for all of the students? I tried the following but Im getting errors. public string HairColor {
        get{ return String.Format ("{0}", (Properties ?? Enumerable.Empty<Property>()).Select(p => p.hair).All()); }
    }

Comment: @Carell - doesn't the class `StudentInfo` contain the data for a single student, then if there is more than one student, the outer `Rootobject` would have multiple entries in the `students` array?

Comment: No. With the following I am able to get the names of all the students. I am trying to do the same with "hair". public string StudentName {
            get{ return String.Format ("{0}", name); }
        }

Comment: @Carell - Then, could you edit your question to include JSON with multiple students, so I can see what you want?

Comment: Ok I edited the question. The JSON now has 4 different students. How would I get "hair" of all 4 students? Can it be done by modifying the code in your answer?

Comment: @Carell - The hair color of all 4 students cannot be gotten as a property on a single `StudentInfo`.  See updated answer.

Comment: The update is not getting all the "hair" data. Its getting only the first one. Also I need to do this inside my View Model in order to populate the list view.

Comment: @Carell - Here's a working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VZ68fG) showing what I have so far.  Beyond that I can't help you because we seem to be having some communication problems.

Comment: Im such a dummy. The reason why I was getting only the first result is that I have posted the wrong JSON. I know I am asking for too much at this point but can you rewrite public string HairColor {} and public string MathGrade {} for the updated JSON? I tried myself but couldn't manage. I have edited my question with the correct JSON.

Comment: Also after replacing the json with the updated json, dotnetfiddle doesn't work.